# What should I do when error says - Identifier "velocity" not declared in the current scope?

Tags: godot4

```
func _physics_process(delta):
    if direction:
        velocity.x = direction.x * SPEED
        velocity.y = direction.y * SPEED
    else:
        velocity.x = move_toward(velocity.x, 0, SPEED)
        velocity.y = move_toward(velocity.y, 0, SPEED)
    move_and_slide()
```

I didn't try anything, the error is:
`Identifier "velocity" not declared in the current scope`

Answer (score 0):

I assume you copy-pasted some code from the web. You do not define `velocity` so this will not work unless your node has a `velocity` property itself.

`CharacterBody2D` has a `velocity` that is used for `move_and_slide()` so you might want to check if your script is attached to a `CharacterBody2D` node and not something else.